# How to copy records from one table to another without duplicates in MySQL where UNIQUE KEY is set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `users_exam_question_answer` with the following records in `mysql` table. Now, I want to copy records without duplicate values. Herein below row number 2,4,7,8,9 are duplicate records of row number 1. How can I copy all the records to the new table except above row numbers.  Here is my sql table where UNIQUE KEY has set for `user_id`,`exam_id`,`question_id` columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_exam_question_answer` (
  `user_exam_question_answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_answer_option` enum('0','1','2','3','4') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `marks` float DEFAULT '0',
  `createdon` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modion` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_exam_question_answer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_exam_question_answer` (`user_id`,`exam_id`,`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8191 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
`id`,`userid`,`examid`,`question_id`,`answers`
----------------------------------------------
(1, 5259, 25, 226, '4'),
(2, 5259, 25, 226, '4'),
(3, 5259, 25, 227, '2'),
(4, 5259, 25, 226, '4'),
(5, 5259, 25, 228, '1'),
(6, 5259, 25, 229, '3'),
(7, 5259, 25, 226, '4'),
(8, 5259, 25, 226, '4'),
(9, 5259, 25, 226, '4'),
```

How can i solve this? Please help, dataset is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way seems to be

```
INSERT IGNORE ... INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

The unique constraint on table2 will silently drop all duplicate rows, and you will end up inserting only nonduplicate rows **according to your indexes**. Whether this is the desired behaviour or not, only you can say; your question does not specify this clearly.

To be clearer, in your setup say you have,

```
1, 5259, 25, 226, '4'
...
123, 5259, 25, 226, '12'
```

The first row will be inserted (and you'll have a '4' in fifth column), the 123rd will be ignored. Actually, in MySQL there's no hard guarantee on *which* row will be inserted among those that have the same indexed columns. It *usually* is the first, but it might not be. If you need to specify that, i.e., which criteria to insert either the 1st or 123rd row, then the correct answer is - as always :-) - Gordon Linoff's.

Comment: @satyajitbhowmik if an answer solves your problem then click its checkmark and accept it. Take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Comment: Yes, sure it was not known to me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `distinct`?

```
insert into new_table (userid, examid, question_id, answers)
select distinct userid, examid, question_id, answers
from users_exam_question_answer
```

This assumes that the target table has a auto-incremented primary key just like the source table, so there is no need to provide this value for insert.

Comment: Yes, I have tried several ways but getting the error like ```#1062 - Duplicate entry 'xxxx-xx-xxx' for key 'source_table'```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little baffled on what you want.  There are *four* columns that define a unique row, but you are only specifying three for the unique constraint.  That suggests aggregation:

```
select userid, examid, question_id, max(answers)
from users_exam_question_answer
group by userid, examid, question_id;
```

In your example data `answers` is the same when the other three columns have the same values.  The question does not specify that this is necessarily the case, though.

Comment: No, only these columns like `userid`, `examid` but in my case the column `question_id` is duplicate. And I am trying to copy without duplicate question_id for each and every  `userid`, `examid`